# Почему я не могу выбрать данные из элемента с помощью метода jQuery.data?

Tags: jquery

Элемент имеет доп. аттрибут `weight`:

```
<div id="test" weight="75">test</div>

var test = $('#test').get(0);

alert(jQuery.data(test,'weight'));
```

Но в итоге получаю значение `undefined`?

Как я понимаю для того чтобы это срабатывало нужно только сначала задать значение с помощью `jQuery.data( obj, 'attr','value' )`, а если оно уже там было, то только через `$(obj).attr('attr_name')` его можно вытащить?

Comment: почему нужно использовать именно `jQuery.data`?

почему не: 

    var test = $('#test');
    test.data('weight', 75);
    test.data('weight'); // 75

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `data()` - это внутреннее хранилище значений. 
А `attr()` - это метод по работе с атрибутами элементов.

То есть чтобы воспользоваться методом data() и получить какое-то значение, сначала это значение этим же методом и нужно установить.

```
var test = $('#test').get(0);
jQuery.data(test, 'attribute1' ,{ first: 16, last: "pizza!" }); // элемент, ключ, значение

alert(jQuery.data(test,'attribute1'));
```

либо по понятному:

```
var test = $('#test');
test.data('attribute1' ,{ first: 16, last: "pizza!" }); // элемент, ключ, значение
alert(test.data('attribute1'));
```

Метод `attr()` просто работает с атрибутами:

```
<div id="info" height="100">123456</div>
```

js:

```
alert($('#test').attr('height'));
```

Comment: у jQuery.data есть один косяк.. когда данные в дата меняются в ходе исполнения js скриптов, то при получении значения data результат будет дефолтным т.е то что было при загрузке страницы.